# How to substract a column by row?

Tags: r, calculus

I want to do an easy subtract in R, but I don't know how to solve it. I would like to know if I have to do a loop or if there is a function.

I have a column with numeric variables, and I would like to subtract n by n-1.

```
Time_Day Diff
10  10
15  5
45  30
60  15
```

Thus, I would like to find the variable "Diff".

Comment: Take a look at `?diff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also try with package `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, dif=Time_Day-lag(Time_Day))
#   Time_Day Diff dif
# 1       10   10  NA
# 2       15    5   5
# 3       45   30  30
# 4       60   15  15
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need?

Here we save the column as a variable:

```
c <- c(10, 15, 45, 60)
```

Now we add a 0 to the beginning and then cut off the last element:

```
cm1 <- c(0, c)[1:length(c)]
```

Now we subtract the two:

```
dif <- c - cm1
```

If we print that out, we get what you're looking for:

```
dif # 10 5 30 15
```

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer the easy way with diff or dplyr :))

Comment: Glad you found your answer!  Good luck with your project.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

With `diff` :

```
df <- data.frame(Time_Day = c(10, 15, 45, 60))
df$Diff <- c(df$Time_Day[1], diff(df$Time_Day))
df
##  Time_Day Diff
##1       10   10
##2       15    5
##3       45   30
##4       60   15
```

It works fine in `dplyr` too :

```
library("dplyr")
df <- data.frame(Time_Day = c(10, 15, 45, 60))
df %>% mutate(Diff = c(Time_Day[1], diff(Time_Day)))
```